# Why do Xcode product point to wrong location?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

I got a XCode 4.6 project where I build a Ruby C Extension. It started as a Ruby 2.0 project. But I needed to build for Ruby 1.8 as well so I added a target for each version.

**Per-configuration Build Product Path**

*Ruby 2.0 Target*

- **Debug:** build/Debug/2.0.0
- **Release:** build/Release/2.0.0

*Ruby 1.8 Target*

- **Debug:** build/Debug/1.8.6
- **Release:** build/Release/1.8.6

And that all works fine, everything builds fine.

But the .bundle file each target produce doesn't point to the correct location. So they appear red in the list. (Yes, I've done a Release build - files are in the `Release/x.x.x/` folder)

When I click on either of the .bundle products listed they both points to a full path that indicate the Xcode expects to find both files directly under the Release folder. For some reason it's ignoring the sub-path I added.

In fact, it appear to use the Project configuration - because when I change the project config to `build/Release/test` it expects both product to be found there.

Is there some configuration I've missed? Or is this a Xcode bug? Is there a different way one should configure this? (The product name needs to remain the same for both targets.)

(I'm completely new to Xcode.)

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using Xcode5?

Comment: Compatibility with existing projects. Does this not happen in Xcode 5?

Comment: Never happened to me. But that does not mean it doesnt happen! Xcode4 often marked targets as being red for me unless I restarted it.

Comment: In my case Xcode doesn't use the Target build path, but use the Project build path. I'll check on a spare Mac I have if Xcode 5 also does this. If it doesn't then I'll just leave this as a Xcode 4.6 bug.

Comment: You can have both versions installed side-by-side without any issues.